# What is the name of this android menu view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

What is the name of this menu view and how can I make one just like it?

[image]

Comment: That's an AlertDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subclass of Dialog called `AlertDialog`

You can follow the official documentation to create it on yourself:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Also check this example of "Building an Alert Dialog"
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Its just a `Dialog` in android. You can make it by `AlertDialog`

Follow this official documentation. It may help you: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html